# Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address...custom board

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have taken rpi as a reference and trying to boot kernel to our custom board, modified the "dts" file by removing all peripherals except UART and Interrupt controller by changing the base address of the rpi board to our board specific address.

Seeting the env variables as follows,

```
$ setenv initrd 0xc3000000;setenv initrd_high 0xc4000000;setenv fdt_high 0xc1001000;setenv fdt_addr_r 0xc1000000


$ setenv bootargs earlyprintk console=ttyAMA0 mem=128M noinitrd root=/dev/mtdblock3 rw rootfstype=jffs2 rw init=/sbin/init
```

This is the error log we got....

```
 SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1




[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16




[    0.000000] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 48000fe0
[    0.000000] pgd = c0004000




[    0.000000] [48000fe0] *pgd=00000000




[    0.000000] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] ARM




[    0.000000] Modules linked in:




[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper Not tainted 4.9.22+ #81




[    0.000000] Hardware name: BCM2835





[    0.000000] task: c0497f58 task.stack: c0494000





[    0.000000] PC is at __vic_init+0x3c/0x178





[    0.000000] LR is at 0x48000fe0






[    0.000000] pc : [<c0473b74>]    lr : [<48000fe0>]    psr: a00000d3






[    0.000000] sp : c0495f50  ip : 00000000  fp : c0495f7c





[    0.000000] r10: 00000001  r9 : 410fb767  r8 : 48000000






[    0.000000] r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00000000  r5 : ffffffff  r4 : 00000000





[    0.000000] r3 : 48000fe0  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000000







[    0.000000] Flags: NzCv  IRQs off  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  





Segment user
[    0.000000] Control: 00c5387d  Table: c0004008  DAC: 00000055





[    0.000000] Process swapper (pid: 0, stack limit = 0xc0494188)





[    0.000000] Stack: (0xc0495f50 to 0xc0496000)
```

Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem occured in interrupt context in procedure __vic_init. This procedure tried to access virtual address 48000fe0.

By the way - are you sure that this is complete calltrace taken from dmesg? 
If this is only a snippet taken from dmesg - put the whole calltrace here.

If you have sources for this procedure __vic_init you can debug it - I mean find the number of the line in source file and do the further debug.